# gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0 project_name/settings/production.py

Tags: django, gunicorn

$ python manage.py run_gunicorn 0.0.0.0:80 --settings=project_name.settings.production

<- It's run, OK.

but,
$ gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:80 project_name/settings/production.py

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 106, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 102, in load
    return mod.make_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/django_wsgi.py", line 36, in make_wsgi_application
    if get_validation_errors(s):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 94, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
> ImportError: No module named accounts
2013-06-29 01:56:53 [30859] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30859)
2013-06-29 01:56:53 [30854] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-06-29 01:56:53 [30854] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

---

How can I solve this problem?
I want to run on daemon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue related to your `PYTHONPATH`. Try adding the path that contains the `accounts` module to your python path, using gunicorn's [`--pythonpath`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#pythonpath).

If you have newer gunicorn/Django versions using gunicorn via [management command](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#django-manage-py) should be the preffered way - and it should be more safe regarding issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your django app using gunicorn instead of django_gunicorn:

```
$ gunicorn mydjangoproject.wsgi:application
```

There is also an alternative solution to fix the gunicorn_django script, see [here](http://www.dangtrinh.com/2014/09/gunicorn-and-django17.html).  I ran into the issue when upgrading from gunicorn 18.0 to 19.1.1. Cheers!